# Django+Chatterbot no funciona en producción

Tags: python-3.x, django, deployment, windows-server-2012, wampserver

Estoy implementando un chatbot usando el paquete Chatterbot(1.0.5) + chatterbot_corpus(1.2.0) en Django (3.0.5) con python 3.6.5. El chatbot funciona perfectamente en un entorno de desarrollo (`settings.py -> DEBUG = TRUE`).

El problema viene cuando hago el deploy en el servidor, la aplicación no funciona, el navegador se queda cargando y cargando y nunca muestra nada, ni siquiera error. Si quito la app de `INSTALLED_APPS` en `settings.py` el servidor ejecuta el proyecto sin problemas, las demás apps funcionan correctamente.

He hecho el deploy usando Wampserver(apache) + mod_wsgi y también con Microsoft IIS + wfastcgi y sucede exactamente lo mismo. El servidor es un Windows Server 2012R2

El archivo `apache_error.log` de Wampserver muestra lo siguiente:

```
[Tue Jul 14 08:48:24.713279 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10580:tid 436] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Jul 14 08:48:26.726951 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8156:tid 600] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mesa_dco\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in __del__
NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined
```

En Google no he encontrado nada relacionado con ese error o que pueda ayudarme a resolver el problema

Cabe resaltar que ese error solo lo muestra la primera vez que se ejecuta el proyecto cuando el chatterbot está configurado en `INSTALLED_APPS`, si se reinicia el servidor ese error no se vuelve a mostrar y según los logs todo se ejecuta con aparente normalidad como se muestra a continuación:

```
[Tue Jul 14 08:50:32.776398 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9800:tid 548] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Jul 14 08:50:34.780643 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4240:tid 564] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Jul 14 08:50:34.811893 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9800:tid 548] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4240 exited successfully.
[Tue Jul 14 08:50:35.421229 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10280:tid 544] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.3.12 mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 14 08:50:35.421229 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10280:tid 544] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Aug  9 2019 16:46:32
[Tue Jul 14 08:50:35.421229 2020] [core:notice] [pid 10280:tid 544] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.41\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41'
[Tue Jul 14 08:50:35.421229 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10280:tid 544] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8460
[Tue Jul 14 08:50:36.108797 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8460:tid 560] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

No sé si alguien haya tenido el mismo problema o tenga indicios que me puedan ayudar a solucionarlo

Comment: Hice lo mismo que tu.... Yo he intentado aparte de Django, con flask y con bottle... con chatterbot 1.0.8 https://intercongreso.vps.co.ve/toni Con chatterbot 1.0.2 https://intercongreso.vps.co.ve/toninot con uwgi... con gunicorn.... hasta con papelitos de aluminio pegados en la pantalla pero nada... Chatterbot es un engaño.... Dime como lo solucionarse si lo solucionarse por favor....

Comment: @Pedro después de mucho matarme la cabeza funcionó, aunque no hice nada. La primer vez se demora bastante en iniciar la aplicación, aproximadamente 1-2 min. Ya después inicia de inmediato. Parece ser que la librería nltk se demora bastante en cargar. En definitiva simplemente es esperar a que se inicie la app, solo es la primera vez. Espero que sea el mismo caso, suerte!